# Importing a component

Tags: reactjs

This is my first react application ever so properly pretty easy question.

Component to import:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";

const DropdownPaging = props => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
    <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem disabled>Action (disabled)</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />
        <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Quo Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default DropdownPaging;
```

Consuming component:

```
import { DropdownPaging } from "./DropdownPaging";
```

and in my render method I just call the component:

```
<DropdownPaging></DropdownPaging>
```

I get following error:

> Attempted import error: 'DropdownPaging' is not exported from
>   './DropdownPaging'.

I followed this sample:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

Both components is in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error is on the `import statement`:

```
import { DropdownPaging } from "./DropdownPaging";
```

When you import something with the curley braces `{}` you are using what is called a **named import**, but in the **DropdownPaging** you are doing a **default** export so for fixing the error you need to do:

```
import DropdownPaging from "./DropdownPaging";
```

If you want to use **named exports** the solution would be to change the export on the *DropdownPaging* component and leave the import with {}:

```
// In the DropdownPaging component
export DropdownPaging

// In the component doing the import
import DropdownPaging from "./DropdownPaging";
```

You can read more about named vs default exports on this [dev.to article](https://dev.to/laurieontech/exports-and-imports-and-defaults-oh-my-fa3)

I also created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modules-es-6-7x83r) with some examples on how to use the different kinds of imports in Javascript (with ES6)

Answer (score 1):

You export `DropdownPaging` as the `default export`, but imported it like any other export.

Either change the export:

`export DropdownPaging;`

**Or** change the import:

`export DropdownPaging from './DropdownPaging';`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use named export & default export

**-Named exports** from ./MyComponent.js file

```
export const MyComponent1 = () => {}
export const MyComponent2 = () => {}
```

import like this

```
import { MyComponent1, MyComponent2 } from "./MyComponent";
```

**-defult exports** from ./MyComponent.js file

```
   const MyComponent = () => {}
   export default MyComponent;
```

import like this

```
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
```